# Cardinality of an infinite separable connected metric space is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cardinals, connectedness, separable-spaces

How to prove:

Cardinality of an infinite separable connected metric space is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you know how to show a non-trivial connected metric space is uncountable?

Comment: my teacher gave me the same hint when i asked him, but i don't know  really :(

Comment: The easiest proof I know uses Urysohn's lemma.

Comment: i know Urysohn's lemma

Answer (score 6):

Let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $X$. For each $x\in X$ let $\mathscr{B}(x)=\{B(x,2^{-n}):n\in\Bbb N\}$, where as usual $B(x,r)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<r\}$; $\mathscr{B}(x)$ is a local base at $x$. For each $x\in X$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ let $D(x,n)=D\cap B(x,2^{-n})$, and let $\mathscr{D}(x)=\{D(x,n):n\in\Bbb N\}$; $\mathscr{D}(x)$ is a countable family of subsets of $D$. Now show:

1. $D$ has only $2^{\aleph_0}$ distinct countable families of subsets.
2. If $x,y\in X$ and $x\ne y$, then $\mathscr{D}(x)\ne\mathscr{D}(y)$.

This part shows that the cardinality is at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ and doesn’t use connectedness. That comes in when you want to show that the space doesn’t have a smaller cardinality. Remember that $X$ is completely regular, so if you pick a point $x$ and an open set $U$ containing $x$, there is a continuous function $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in X\setminus U$. If $|X|<2^{\aleph_0}$, that map cannot be a surjection; use that to produce a disconnection of $X$.

Comment: Isn't connectedness key? I can think of several infinite separable metric spaces that aren't uncountable.

Comment: @Jacob: It’s not required to show that $2^\omega$ is an upper bound, which is where people usually have trouble. It’s one of several possible conditions ensuring that the space isn’t smaller. Another is having no isolated points.

Comment: "No isolated points" would have to go along with completeness or local compactness or some similar property, otherwise $\mathbb{Q}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Very true; I’ve no idea what I was thinking 11 years ago when I made that comment.

Answer (score 5):

To see that $|X| \ge 2^{\aleph_0}$, we don't need to use complete regularity.  Pick $x \in X$; I claim that for every sufficiently small $r$, say $r < R$, there exists $x_r \in X$ with $d(x, x_r) = r$.  (Suppose not; then you can show that $B(x,r)$ is open and closed.)  Since the points $\{x_r\}$ are necessarily distinct, you have a set of the cardinality of $(0,R)$.

Comment: I don't see why this proves uncountability.  Why doesn't $\mathbb Q$ meet this?

Comment: @RossMillikan: For instance, there are no points at distance $\sqrt{2}$ from the origin (and so $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ is clopen).

Answer (score -3):

To show that $Card(X) \leq َ2^{\aleph_0}$, consider for some x from X the distance map $d(*,x):a \to d(a,x)$. This map is continuous, hence the image is a connected set, of cardinal strictly larger than one. Thus of cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$, so X is also of cardinal larger or equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$.